# order by key array multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional array, and i want to order each array by 'fecha'(i mean 2017-02-20, then 2017-02-21, then 2017-02-22 and finally 2017-02-23). I have read a lot of answers, but they only work with bidimensional arrays. I have tried with unsort and array_multisort, even with ksort bue i couldn´t obtain the desire result.

```
Array
    (
        [0.10] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [fecha] => 2017-02-21
                        [tarifa] => 743.80
                        [percent] => 0.10
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [fecha] => 2017-02-22
                        [tarifa] => 743.80
                        [percent] => 0.10
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [fecha] => 2017-02-20
                        [tarifa] => 743.80
                        [percent] => 0
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [fecha] => 2017-02-23
                        [tarifa] => 743.80
                        [percent] => 0
                    )

            )

        [0.15] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [fecha] => 2017-02-21
                        [tarifa] => 743.80
                        [percent] => 0.15
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [fecha] => 2017-02-22
                        [tarifa] => 743.80
                        [percent] => 0.15
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [fecha] => 2017-02-20
                        [tarifa] => 743.80
                        [percent] => 0
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [fecha] => 2017-02-23
                        [tarifa] => 743.80
                        [percent] => 0
                    )

            )

    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with `strtotime` to order by date.

***ASC Order by date (fecha):***

```
foreach ($yourArray as $key => $subarray) {
    usort($subarray, function($a, $b) {
            return strtotime($a['fecha']) - strtotime($b['fecha']);
        });
    $yourArray[$key] = $subarray;
 }

print_r($yourArray);
```

***DESC order by date (fecha):***

```
foreach ($yourArray as $key => $subarray) {
    usort($subarray, function($a, $b) {
            return strtotime($b['fecha']) - strtotime($a['fecha']);
        });
    $yourArray[$key] = $subarray;
 }

print_r($yourArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    foreach ($yourArray as $key => &$subarray) {
        usort($subarray, function($a, $b) {
            return $a['fecha'] <= $b['fecha'];
        });
    }
    print_r($yourArray); //now it's sorted
```